# Converting $3$-variable truth table to 3CNF

Tags: logic, computer-science, propositional-calculus, conjunctive-normal-form

I have a truth table for length $3$ binary strings, say $110$ and $001$ map to $1$ and everything else to $0$. Is there an an algorithm to represent this table as a 3CNF which is satisfied only by $110$ and $001$?

Comment: Focus on the inputs producing $0$ outputs instead. Google "product of sums".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, rewrite rules can be used:
$$(A \land B \land  C) \rightarrow (A \land B) \land C$$
$$ A \lor (B \land C) \rightarrow (A \lor B) \land (A \lor C)$$
$$(A \land B) \lor C \rightarrow C \lor (A \land B)$$

The input is
$$(X \land Y \land \neg Z) \lor (\neg X \land \neg Y \land Z)$$ where $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ are Boolean variables.